# Converting 3.3-5 V range to 0-5 V range

Tags: voltage, gpio, attiny85

I need to solve a problem with connecting a wireless charger (cheap chinese one without datasheet) to a microcontroller (ATtiny85).

If the phone is not placed on the charger, there is 5 V in the signal, if the phone is placed on the charger and charging, there is 3.3 V.

I need this signal to be passed to the microcontroller with a digital input. However, it only responds to 0-1 V as LOW and 3-5 V as HIGH. How to convert the 3.3-5 V range from the charger to 0-5 V for the microcontroller?

I tried a Schmitt trigger, but don't know how to go low under 1 V.

Comment: You need a 'comparator'.   https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/analog/article/21805906/beyond-the-op-ampdesigning-with-ic-comparators

Comment: the attiny85 does have an ADC, so it may work to just use that, so then you dont need any external components

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx1H1R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image]

The Microchip [ATtiny85](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf) GPIO pins are ST so this should be adequate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is a non-inverting HCMOS gate and a resistor divider.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work reliably. For \$V_{CC}=4.5V: V_{IH,MIN} = 3.15V, V_{IL,MIN} = 1.35V\$. Here the gate input is **3.11V** and **2.05V** for VG1 = **5V** and **3.3V**, respectively.